# Fixed menu cut off when smaller than window

Tags: html, css

I've been looking for a solution to a problem for a long time: I have a menu that scrolls, so it's fixed in position. but when the window is smaller than the menu, part of it is cut off. What options do I have?
The menu opens when clicking on a hamburger.

```
    <div id="container-menu">
        <div id="menuinhalt">
            <div id="menu"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="menu" /></div>
            <div id="gesucht-aufklappen">Häufig gesucht</div>
            <div id="gesucht"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="gesucht" style="html5" /></div>
        </div>
        <div id="about">
            <div id="menu-about"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="menu-about" /></div>
            <div id="submenu-about"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="submenu-about" /></div>
            <div id="socialmedia"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="socialmedia" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
#container-menu { display: none; background: #00436e; position: fixed; z-index: 999; left: 0px; right: 0px; }
```

i tried overflow scroll, however that doesn't work and wouldn't find that a great solution as i then have two scrollbars.

Comment: You haven't provided much information for reproduction. Specifically, you mentioned that the container was fixed to the top, but even that is hidden. Regarding the menu, which is the focus of the question, you didn't provide any code. **Could you please expand your answer with a sample that can be used to reproduce the overflow issue?**

Comment: If the menu's height is more than the window height what do you want to happen if you don't want the user to be able to scroll it by itself? How are they to scroll it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using percentage width:

```css
#container-menu { 
  display: none;
  background: #00436e; 
  position: fixed; 
  z-index: 999; 
  left: 0px; 
  right: 0px; 
  width: 100%;
}
#menuinhalt {
  width: 100%;
}
.menu-item {
  width: 70%;
}
```

Now add class `"menu-item"` to every menu item in the menu.

```html
<div class="menu-item" ... > ... </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
#container-menu {
  max-width: 100%; // or 100vh for full screen viewport
}
```